# Transitioning to (WebSocket)GraphQL Subscription-Based Data Management in React Native

Tags: websocket, socket.io, graphql-subscriptions, real-time-updates

I am developing a React Native App where I use GraphQL queries for GET calls, Axios for POST calls, GraphQL Subscriptions for real-time updates.

I also have an offline save feature that stores data locally (SqlLite). When device reconnects, I trigger a POST call to save drafts, a GET call to get latest data and then, enable subscriptions.

I am wondering if I can unify the whole process by switching all POST, GET calls in React Native app to Subscriptions (Websocket).

My concerns are

- Handling success/error responses (which is straightforward with Axios/GraphQL & potentially bit complex with subscriptions)
- Significant time investment required for this transition.

**Questions**

1. Is it beneficial to make this switch?
2. Are there any challenges associated with transferring large volume of data via subscription protocol, particularly through WebSocket technology?